"Resolving Missing Data in 'At Risk' Table at Specific Time Points in Kaplan-Meier Plot Using RStudio"
I am trying to create a Kaplan-Meier curve and an "at risk" table using RStudio with data that includes status (1 or 0 to indicate the presence or absence of an event), time (time of event occurrence), and group (two groups: A group or B group) :

However, the following code fails to display the numbers at the 720-day mark in the "at risk" table. Could you provide a solution to this issue?
# Load necessary packages
install.packages("survival")
install.packages("survminer")

library(survival)
library(survminer)

# Create (or load) the data
data <- data.frame(
  status = c(1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0),
  time = c(100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800),
  group = c('A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B')
)

# Fit the Kaplan-Meier model
fit <- survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ group, data = data)

# Plot the Kaplan-Meier curve with the "at risk" table
ggsurvplot(
  fit,
  data = data,
  risk.table = TRUE,
  risk.table.height = 0.25,
  xlim = c(0, 800),
  xscale = "d",
  break.time.by = 180,
  risk.table.y.text.col = TRUE,
  risk.table.y.text = FALSE,
  risk.table.col = "strata",
  ggtheme = theme_minimal()
)


Neither your data nor your code produces the figure you provided. And there is no "d" value for the xscale argument. Days are the default time units.

Adding an extra time point, while not recommended, can be done by summarising the fit at that particular time point and then extracting the number at risk. Here's an example using the built-in lung dataset from the survival package.
# Fit the Kaplan-Meier model
fit <- survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ sex, data = lung)

# Plot the Kaplan-Meier curve with the "at risk" table
ggsurvplot(fit, data = lung,
  palette=c("blue","red"),
  risk.table = TRUE,
  risk.table.height = 0.25,
  xlim = c(0, 1200),
  break.time.by = 220,
  risk.table.y.text.col = TRUE,
  risk.table.y.text = FALSE,
  risk.table.col = "strata",
  ggtheme = theme_classic()
) -> p

extra_time_point <- 960
Sfit <- summary(fit, times=extra_time_point)

You can then modify the risk table with annotate and scale_x_continuous:
p$table <- p$table + 
  annotate("text", x = Sfit$time, y = c(2,1), 
           label = Sfit$n.risk, size=4.5, col=c("blue", "red")) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(seq(0,1200,220), extra_time_point))
p


